# Google chrome doesnt load favicon

Tags: html, favicon

I opened Chrome's developers tools and it doesn't load my favicon at all when I looked for it at networks tab.
Here is my code:

```
<DOCTYPE HTML>
<head>
    <link rel="icon" href='./img/favicon.ico' type="image/x-icon"/>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Website</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>
```

Comment: try  href="./favicon.ico"

Comment: @scaisEdge its not working

Comment: work with other broswer or not?

Comment: it works with mozilla

Comment: Browsers cache the favicon and clearing cache does not always help. Type the full url of the favicon to a new browser tab and then refresh your page. This usually works for me.

Comment: Again not working, its driving me crazy...

Answer (score 2):

Try this one:

`<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />`

Answer (score 1):

Upload your favicon.ico to the root directory of your website and that should work with Chrome. Some browsers disregard the meta tag and just use /favicon.ico

Go figure?.....

Answer (score 0):

Try adding  type  type="image/x-icon"

```
<link rel="icon" href='./favicon.ico' type="image/x-icon"/>
```

and try move the favicon.ico in an subdir  /img

then

```
 <link rel="icon" href='./img/favicon.ico' type="image/x-icon"/>
```

or with shortcut icon

```
 <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="./img/favicon.ico" />
```

or  save the ico like a png

```
 <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="./img/favicon.png" />
```

Comment: done that and still npt working i have tried almost everything apparently it doesnt work

Comment: I have update the answer ..in not work  show all the head code

Comment: i updated the question, tried that still not working

Comment: Try forcing a reload ctrl+F5  or  Ctrl-Shift-R (ignore cache)

Comment: Try moving the row with the link icon below the meta charset

Comment: i moved it under every row and still nothing, its driving me crazy for weeks now, is there anything else i can do to display the favicon without the html tag or idk?

Answer (score 0):

Seems there's no issue with your code attributes.This is the standerd form

```
<link rel="icon" href="imagelocation" type="image/x-icon" sizes="16x16">
```

Try a Image from internet without downloading and make verify that it's not a issue of Chrome first.Then take a look to your code and location of the image are matching correctly with your location of file you have call your Favicon.

Accroding to your tag your favicon should be in a sub directory called 'img'.This may be a browser cacheing issue also. Try viewing page source (Right Click > View Page Source ) and go to the location of the image and try reload it.

Comment: I have tried an online favicon and it didnt do anything, i have tried reloading with ctrl+shift+r to ignore the cache and still nothing, tried in other pcs and again the same result

Comment: remove that ./ part and try again.. href="img/favicon.ico" .. and try adding your favi to root directory. If its already in the root directory why you using that /img part in your tag ?

Comment: moved it back and forth its not doing the trick, removed the ./ still nothing